# "Data is" or "Data are"? Which for which context?

Tags: colloquialisms

"The data are highly useful in uncovering..."

"Data is key to medical research."

Both are phrases which are used. Are both correct? It seems to me that the second, which in my understanding is wrong, actually is a shortening of "The *usage of* data is key to medical research."

What version is correct? And if I'm doing marketing, (which might be the reason I'm coming here) which is more appropriate in that context, as there is a balance there between coming across as correct versus appearing deliberately esoteric?

Comment: I trust my answer there cuts to the chase (after comparing the way we handle 'news'). Neither usage is incorrect, but (a) with everyday situations, 'the data is' is far more usual / (b) some academic institutions prefer  'the data are'. This can be useful for 'sets of data' (but isn't really a felicitous usage).  Here, one needs to consult the relevant in-house style guide where appropriate, or make one's own mind up where not.

Comment: Your second sentence, which is not addressed by the duplicate, is perfectly natural in formal contexts because you are using it naturally (without the 'the') as a mass noun, similar to 'Milk is good for you'. But to emphasize (and qualify slightly) @EdwinAshworth's point, 'The data are useful ...' (referring to specific set of instances) is only used in medical and other highly technical journals and formal speech. For the great majority of other writing and speech (newspapers and such), people use 'The data is ...' or 'The data shows...'. So use 'The data is...'